# How to find occurrences of a specific string within an unordered list in ColdFusion?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

Our database stores a "table of contents" for each issue of our magazine as an unordered list. I want to create an "Articles related to #specificString#" page, so I'd like to query for the Table of Contents, and then find and display only those list items containing that specific string.

For example, suppose the specific string is "bumblebee," and the stored table of contents list is like so:

```
<ul>
<li>"The Secret Life of the Honeybee" by Anonymous</li>
<li>I got stung by a bumblebee!</li>
<li>"Flight of the Bumblee" was composed by Rimsky-Korsakov.</li>
<li>"The Case of the Disappearing Honeybee" by A. Conan Doyle, 1904</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to match and display the text from the second and third list item but not the first or the fourth. I do not need to return the HTML -- only the relevant text. Conversely, if I could bleep out any list items that do NOT contain the relevant text, that would be fine as well!

I have tried

```
REMatchNoCase("<li>.*bumblebee.*</li>", text)
```

which finds all list items, even those that do not contain "bumblebee." Any suggestions or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: jSoup  - http://jsoup.org/ - is designed for parsing HTML like this.

Comment: Your regex is being greedy; the `*` will match every character after the bumblee, up to the last closing `</li>`.  Try `REMatchNoCase("<li>.*?bumblebee.*?</li>", text)`

Comment: Thanks Duncan, that does indeed prevent any list items after the last bumblebee from being matched! Sweet! I thought we were good to go, but I started checking some other tables of contents that had been returned, and saw that any list items *before* "bumblebee" were also being returned, even if they did not contain "bumblebee."

Comment: BTW I edited my original question to show what I mean, if there are list items before the first list item containing "bumblebee." Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hey Dan thanks for the reply. I don't think this will work for me, as the entirety of the unordered list in my example above -- HTML and all -- is a single field. "Where somefield like '%bumblebee%'" would return the whole shooting match, I guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use negation of the terms you want to enclosure your match instead of `.*`.

You can do this:

```
<li>[^>]*bumblebee[^<]*</li>
```

Here is [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cA2rN1/2)

Comment: Hey Thanks Rodrigo, that worked! As it turned out, the authors' names were in a span tag, and I did not need the list item tags, so I was able to use "<cfset articleList = REMatchNoCase("[^>]*#aircraftDesignation#[^<]*<span[^>]*[^<]*</span>", content)>" and it is working fine! There are a few database records that do not match this format exactly, but we can go back in and change them manually. This will be a great help, Rodrigo! Many thanks!